# CSS div positioning (original state)

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a basic system but stying has to be done with divs.

The thing is, I'm always messing my div styling when I do it myself. Like, a div goes out of container div and things like that.

What I'm trying to archieve is very basic.

- There should be a 800x800 container div.
- The first 200px height and 600px width should contain a new div named
  description.
- 200px width on right side should be a new div named logo.
- There should be another div here, 200px height and 800px width.
- In the bottom, we got 400px height and 800px width to use. I want to
  make it something like this: (all 400px) height.

  From left to right;

100px - a div named block (contains a block image) 150px - a div named item-1. 100px - a div named block (contains a block image) 150px - a div named item-2. 100px - a div named block (contains a block image) 150px - a div named item-3. 100px - a div named block (contains a block image)

Could anybody help me in this case? A little example will get my going.

Thank you.

Comment: This not looks like a question, this looks like task. That's simple, but I have no desire to solve it instead of you (and I sure, that I'm not the one with such ideas).

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @Diodeus; To make it fairly easy for you, imagine a div like a square. Then imagine 2 squares in that div with %50 width and height. (as a child)

Comment: @AnılÜnal - He means provide a drawing of what you want your end result to look like, instead of trying to describe it in words.

Comment: @Shauna I believe anyone can imagine two 20px square boxes inside a 40px box. Should I really draw it?

Comment: @AnılÜnal - Yes, because we can't see into your mind and ensure that what you're saying is actually what you're thinking. Also, your description is far more than "two 20px square boxes inside a 40px box".

Comment: @Shauna; That's why I minified it for you. Once I get this sorted, I can do the rest myself. It's just an addition of more divs in the same container. If you want to see a live example, see: http://www.sobafire.com/__crap/views/main.php. You'll see the transparent div and two additional divs inside. With my current styling, the text goes outside of the div. (see example) That's why I wanted to have a styling example. Making div inside another div with no css parameters just cause problems.

Comment: @AnılÜnal - Even "minified", you're still using text to try to describe what would be better conveyed in a picture. That is the point Diodeus was trying to make.

Comment: God... I'm just gonna delete my question.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should help you. Your total width goes out of 800px so I have increased the width to 850px.

```
<body>
<div style="width:850px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div style="height:400px; width:100px; float:left" name="block"></div>
    <div style="height:400px; width:150px; float:left" name="item-1"></div>
    <div style="height:400px; width:100px; float:left" name="block"></div>
    <div style="height:400px; width:150px; float:left" name="item-2"></div>
    <div style="height:400px; width:100px; float:left" name="block"></div>
    <div style="height:400px; width:150px; float:left" name="item-3"></div>
    <div style="height:400px; width:100px; float:left" name="block"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @VIDesignz - Floated elements are removed from the normal flow of the document, which causes the parent element to collapse. `clear: both` forces the sibling element to position itself after the floated elements, which, in turn, expands the parent element. (Details with pics can be found in the CSS-Tricks link in my answer.)

Comment: @Shauna Thank you! That makes perfect sense...very useful!

Answer (score -1):

First, most people here don't take kindly to being asked to do your work for you, which is basically what you're asking here. You'll be far better off trying what you're looking to do, then coming back here with specific questions.

That said, I'm going to instead try to help you with the issue that lies underneath your stated question, given the notes within your post.

It sounds to me like you don't have a good understanding of floats, and how they affect HTML elements (and their parent elements). [CSS-Tricks has a phenomenal article on floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). In short, applying `float` to an element takes it out of the normal flow of HTML documents and allows you to align block-level elements next to one another. Issues arise when all child elements of a container are `float`ed, which makes the parent container collapse on itself. This collapsing effect can also happen when one child element is `float`ed, but another one isn't, and the non-`float`ed element takes up less vertical space than the `float`ed one. In that situation, the parent "collapses" to that smaller childe element, leaving the larger floated one overflowing the parent. Once you understand how floats (and float clearing) work, your life will be a lot easier.

Additionally, you might also want to look into `display: inline-block;`, which can solve a number of headaches with things like horizontal navigation.

**Edit** From the looks of the site you linked, another one of your issues is that you're trying to fix the height of your container elements, then making the child elements total height add up to more than the parent. For that, [I refer you back to CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/), for information on the CSS box model.

In short, though, if you have a box that's 2 feet tall, and inside it you stack two more boxes, one that is 1 foot tall, and one that is 1.5 feet tall, then the inside boxes will stick out of the container, because their height adds up to more than the height of the container. The same concept applies to web design, especially when you're using fixed sizes.

Comment: @AnılÜnal - The problem that I see with your question and your comments is that you don't seem to have a solid grasp of the basics of web design/development. Your best bet is going to be study up on the concepts I've linked above, so that you know *why* you're having the overflow issues that you keep having.